# wordpress - php and javascript dont go well together

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I know some `HTML` and `CSS` but zero `JAVA` or `PHP`. I would like to insert **LineIt button** into my `functions.php` in `WordPress`:

**The code goes like this:**

```
<a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?<?php the_title(); ?>%0D%0A<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="imgpath" alt="LINE it!" /></a>
```

Unfortunately this will display only the line link without my **permalink**. The_Permalink will be display as text not as dynamically taken `URL`.

**I tried to do something like this:**

```
<a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/' . the_permalink( '/' ) . '"><img src="linkin" width="[Width of Button]" height="[Height of Button]" alt="LINE it!" /></a>'
```

But of course that didn't work. Oh and I don't want to use tags `<script >`.

Could help?

Thanks

Here is the *function* in my `functions.php` that I'm trying to modify with custom "**LineIT**" button:

```
function show() {

    $return = '<aside class="show1 show2">'
            . show_content() .
            '<div class="show-box">'
            . apply_filters('show_filter', show_rander()) .
            '<div class="show3">'
            . getIcons() .
            '</div></div>**<a href="line.me/R/msg/text/' . the_permalink( '/' ) . '"><img src="linkin" width="[Width of Button]" height="[Height of Button]" alt="LINE it!" /></a>**<div style="clear:both;"></div>'
            . show_content()
            . show_content2() .
            '</aside>

    return apply_filters('show_buttons', $return);
}
```

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: thanks for quick answer - i know there is a second code for script in lineit 

<span>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.line.me/js/line-button.js?v=20140411" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
new media_line_me.LineButton({"pc":false,"lang":"en","type":"a"});
</script>
</span>

which i guess is java? As i stated at the top - i know nothing about php / java but i would like to make this piece of code work. If you have idea please share. Thanks

but i cannot use direclty tags <  script > in my code therefore the first example is the one i would like to modify.

Comment: @j.doe What does this return or output in the response? check this by View Source on a page and look for the generated code where it is supposed to print your link.
Other question, is it Javascript that you mean? I can't see how this is related to Java.
Did you follow instructions on [https://media.line.me/howto/en/](https://media.line.me/howto/en/) ?

Comment: Hi @Braza, ok clearly this title is confusing. I have change it to php / javascript. I hope that will narrow down better with more related answers.

I have implemented the first code and it returned a button with "http://line.me/R/msg/text/" as a url BUT it did not generated the_permalink from my website as the ending. So it seems that the functions.php is not reading <?php the_permalink(); ?> as dynamic link.

Comment: I tried to remove the <?php thus the second code in the main question. Yes it works ... but it does not display "http://line.me/R/msg/text/"

I know this is really simple quesiton and it is a matter of correctly implemented dots and comas with spaces ' . ' code ' .  etc

thats why i need someone who knows even just the basics of php/javascript to make it work

Comment: could you please copy paste the exact script you use in functions.php?

Comment: If you are writing somewhere inside `<?php ... ?>` then you should use : 
`'<a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?'.the_title().'%0D%0A'.the_permalink().'"><img src="imgpath" alt="LINE it!" /></a>'`

Comment: I have updated main topic with function im trying to modify. As for your code ... once implemented below <div><div> it crash the page with error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'href' (T_STRING)

Comment: ok, first things first, you have a few missing characters at the end of your variable declaration `'</aside>` should be `'</aside>';` Try with is already and I ll keep looking

Comment: Can you confirm that the functions show_content(), show_content2() and getIcons() exist and are working correctly? Do you have access to a log file? can you see any displayed errors? Try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the beginning of functions.php, this will display errors if there are any

Comment: `function show() {
     $return = '<aside class="show1 show2">'
        . show_content() .
        '<div class="show-box">'
        . apply_filters('show_filter', show_rander()) .
        '<div class="show3">'
        . getIcons() .
        '</div></div>**<a href="line.me/R/msg/text/' . the_permalink( '/' ) . '"><img src="linkin" width="[Width of Button]" height="[Height of Button]" alt="LINE it!" /></a>**<div style="clear:both;"></div>'
        . show_content()
        . show_content2() .
        '</aside>';
return apply_filters('show_buttons', $return);
}`

Comment: THanks @Braza for involvement :) Yes entire functions works perfectly fine. Only when im trying to add custom <a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/? ...... Below <div><div> it either wont read <php or it will display not a custom link. Maybe tell me how would you cade in functions.php simple string that creates a button with link to http://line.me/R/msg/text/? + ending will be dynamically taken url? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. according to the document at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink, the `the_permalink()` function is usually applied in the template within `The Loop`. Whereas functions.php is usually provide convenient functions and register them for the future use or register in The Loop.
   So put `the_permalink()` in functions.php might not work as what you expected.
2. The general template files are like home.php, page.php or category-6.php(which will provide specific template for the category with id as 6).
   In these files, the Loop usually is like:

   `<?php
   if(have_posts()){
       while(have_posts():
           the_post();
           the_content();
   ?>
   //here you can add the link 
   <a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?<?php the_title(); ?>%0D%0A<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="imgpath" alt="LINE it!" /></a>
   <?php
       endwhile;
   endif;?>`

Please refer to this page https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action for further knowledge of the loop.

3. if you really want to use the functions.php, I would suggest using the other function `get_permalink($id)` and `get_the_title($id)` which will get the permalink of the post by the id and add a function for it. so the function will be:

   `function get_line($id){
       $url = get_permalink($id);
       $title = get_the_title($id);
       return '<a href="http://line.me/R/msg/text/?'.$title.'%0D%0A'.$url.'"><img src="imgpath" alt="LINE it!" /></a>';
    }`

and then call the function in The Loop of the template.

To learn more about wordpress template, please refer https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @j.doe, I just read carefully again with the update from @Braza, I think I might missed some part like `apply_filters`, I am not quite familiar with `apply_filters`. The answer I provided is basically based on the first two paragraphs, so if you have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @lhrec_106 I have used 3rd option and modified code works like a charm. Thanks!

I have inserted function get_line($id) before my function and then simply entered 
. get_line($id) inside my custom function. Button works and share via Line my dynamically generated url.

Thank you